# Trying to make a Batch File that detects unauthorized connections via netstat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a little bit of a dilemma going on right now. You see I am trying to make a batch app that will detect unknown connections from saved connections in a text file. Somehow I need the app to compare the netstat results to the one's in the text file. Here's what I tried:

```
if %netstat -b 5% equ c:\list.txt goto :win
else goto :fail
```

Now I did try to find a solution but to no avail. Maybe I am doing something wrong? Or is there another way of doing this? I want the netstat command to compare the results to what was logged in the text file. Please help me!

Comment: That certainly isn't valid syntax for the IF command. You might try reading the help file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will do what you're after.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('netstat -b 5') do (
    findstr /c:"%%f" c:\list.txt && (
        echo Allowed %%f 
    ) || (
        echo Disallowed %%f
    )
)
```

This will iterate over each line of output from `netstat -b 5`. (Note this is really slow so for testing I redirected the output to netstat.output and then just loaded the file instead).

Description:

- `For /F` - iterate over each line that comings from the command / file in brackets.
- `tokens=3` - get me the 3rd token (the remote address)
- `%%f` - name of the variable
- `'netstat -b 5'` or `netstat.output` - the source of the lines to iterate over
- `do` - the command to run

Then we launch `findstr` and tell it to look for a string `%%f` in the file `c:\list.txt`. If it succeeds the `&&` command will run echoing this address. Otherwise if the string is not found the `||` command will run